# unable to run oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to oracle and write a complex stored procedure to select different data on the basis of different conditions. I am not able to run my stored procedure, it gives following error:

```
ORA-06550: line2, column 3:
PLS-00905: object SAURAV.LOG_DETAIL is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement Ignored
ORA-06512: at line 58
```

My code is given below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE LOG_DETAIL(
    startIndex IN INT
    ,pageSize IN INT
    ,branchId IN varchar2
    ,customerId IN varchar2
    ,fromDate IN DATE
    ,toDate IN DATE
    ,withDate IN INT
    ,p_cursor OUT sys_refcursor
    ) AS
BEGIN
IF withDate = 1 then
        IF branchId = NULL then
            IF customerId = 'All' then
                OPEN p_cursor
                FOR SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY id
                ) AS MyRows
            ,log_info.branch_id
            ,branch_name
            ,customer_id
            ,in_time
            ,out_time
            ,date_time
            ,ip
            ,(
                SELECT COUNT(id)
                FROM log_info
                WHERE date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%' AND toDate || '%'
                ) AS RowNumber  FROM log_info,branch_info
        WHERE date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%' AND toDate || '%'
            AND branch_info.branch_id = log_info.branch_id
        )
    WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
            ELSE
            OPEN p_cursor 
            FOR SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY id
                ) AS MyRows
            ,log_info.branch_id
            ,branch_name
            ,customer_id
            ,in_time
            ,out_time
            ,date_time
            ,ip
            ,(
                SELECT COUNT(id)
                FROM log_info
                WHERE customer_id = customerId
                    AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
                        AND toDate || '%'
                ) AS RowNumber
        FROM log_info,branch_info
        WHERE customer_id = customerId
            AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
                AND toDate || '%'
            AND log_info.branch_id = branch_info.branch_id
        )
    WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
            AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
END IF;
ELSE
    IF customerId = 'All' then
        OPEN p_cursor
        FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            WHERE branch_id = branchId
                AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
                    AND toDate || '%'
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE log_info.branch_id = branchId
        AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
            AND toDate || '%'
        AND branch_info.branch_id = log_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
        ELSE
        OPEN p_cursor
        FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            WHERE branch_id = branchId
                AND customer_id = customerId
                AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
                    AND toDate || '%'
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE log_info.branch_id = branchId
        AND customer_id = customerId
        AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%'
            AND toDate || '%'
        AND log_info.branch_id = branch_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
        END IF ;
        END IF ;
        ELSE
        IF customerId = 'All' then
            IF branchId = NULL then
                OPEN p_cursor
                FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE branch_ingo.branch_id = log_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
        ELSE
        OPEN p_cursor
        FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            WHERE branch_id = branchId
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE log_info.branch_id = branchId
        AND log_info.branch_id = branch_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
        END IF ;
        ELSE
        IF branchId = NULL then
        OPEN p_cursor
        FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            WHERE customer_id = customerId
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE customer_id = customerId
        AND branch_info.branch_id = log_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex + pageSize - 1;
        ELSE
        OPEN p_cursor
        FOR SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS MyRows
        ,log_info.branch_id
        ,branch_name
        ,customer_id
        ,in_time
        ,out_time
        ,date_time
        ,ip
        ,(
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM log_info
            WHERE customer_id = customerId
                AND branch_id = branchId
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM log_info
        ,branch_info
    WHERE customer_id = customerId
        AND log_info.branch_id = branchId
        AND log_info.branch_id = branch_info.branch_id
    )
WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
        AND startIndex || pageSize - 1;
        END IF ;
    END IF ;
END IF ;
END LOG_DETAIL;
```

I am executing procedure using following command:

```
 variable z refcursor;
 LOG_DETAIL(1,20,null,'All',null,null,0,z);
```

After Executing following query:

```
select * from all_errors where name='LOG_DETAIL' order by sequence
```

I got following Result:

```
OWNER   NAME            TYPE         SEQUENCE  LINE    POSITION       TEXT                                       ATTRIBUTE  MESSAGE_NUMBER
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   1   30  49  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   2   30  57  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   3   30  29  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   4   30  39  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   5   32  47  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   6   32  55  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   7   32  27  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   8   32  37  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   9   54  11  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   10  54  19  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   11  53  28  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   12  53  38  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   13  59  9   PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   14  59  17  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   15  58  26  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   16  58  36  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   17  84  10  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   18  84  18  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   19  83  27  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
SAURAV  LOG_DETAIL  PROCEDURE   20  83  37  PLW-07204: conversion away from column type may result in sub-optimal query plan    WARNING  7204
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

**Edit:** Stack trace is added.

Comment: Are you sure you created the procedure under the user SAURAV? Check with: `select object_name, owner from all_objects where object_name = 'LOG_DETAIL'`. If  yes, then please post your execute statement

Comment: yes and I am trying to run it via sql developer ide provided by oracle under same connection

Comment: @JWK when I fire your query froom command line I got following result:

OBJECT_NAME                    OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
LOG_DETAIL                     SAURAV

Comment: Great, then there must me an error somewhere in the passing of the parameters. Can you update your questions with the execute command? You can also right click the object in `sqldeveloper` and select `run`. You can test the invocation that way and compare it with yours.

Comment: Does your proc have errors?  Try `select * from all_errors where name='LOG_DETAIL' order by sequence`

Comment: A couple of remarks not directly related to your question: 1) you compare dates with ... between fromDate ||'%' - why do you do this? Are you relying implicitly on a certain date format (bad, bad idea)? 2) Instead of duplicating the code for your query N times, use one query, and add the filter clauses dynamically (using sys_context or similar)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Are you trying to say I need to copy all data to cursor and then filter it as per condition, if so can you provide me some sample. I am unable to get some proper tutorial for that.

Comment: Check if you get a result with `select * from user_objects where status = 'INVALID' and object_name = 'LOG_DETAIL';` if so, recompile the procedure and check for compilation errors. If not, try the `run` option from sqldeveloper

Comment: I think that @FrankSchmitt is asking "Why are you concatenating a '%' character onto a DATE?", which is a fair question.  There's no point to doing so that I can see - this doesn't create some kind of magic wildcard (SQL wildcarding only works in a LIKE condition) it only forces the DATE value to be converted to a character string and then tacks a % onto the end, for reasons which I am not able to comprehend.  But, at the same time, I don't think that's the root cause of your problem.  Do a `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'LOG_DETAIL'` to see if errors exist.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Adittya all of those warnings listed are due to the conversions you're doing on dates `AND date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%' AND toDate || '%'` is crazy. you're implicitly converting the dates to strings which is not good practice. instead do `AND date_time >= trunc(fromDate) AND date_time < trunc(toDate) + 1`

Comment: @JWK I tried that but the problem is that it is not showing this procedure like other, it call same procedure with procedure name in its ***begin*** and ***end*** block i.e. 
BEGIN
  LOG_DETAIL();
END;

Answer (score 1):

Warning messages are caused by strings containing such expressions:

```
date_time BETWEEN fromDate || '%' AND toDate || '%'
```

Why appending percent signs?  Try to remove them and to recreate your procedure to make it valid.

Comment: I have removed them but still not able to run procedure.
When i run it using sql developer ide provided by oracle it got following syntax in execution block:
*** BEGIN LOG_DETAIL(); END; ***

Comment: @Adittya - What's your errors now (from all_errors) ?  Is procedure valid?  `select status from user_objects where object_name = 'LOG_DETAIL'`

Comment: Its status is invalid. How can I make it valid procedure. What could be the reasons for that??

Comment: It gives no error. I tries using following command:
***select * from all_errors where name='LOG_DETAIL' and attribute='Error'***

Comment: Have you tried openeing the procedure in sqldeveloper and compile it manually? The errors will be shown immediately if any.

Comment: @Adittya - without `attribute='Error'` please

Comment: Then I got warning which I have already mentioned in my question and also with suggestions I am able to solve some of them.

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is the lines which read

```
ELSE
  IF customerId = 'All' then
```

This should be

```
ELSIF customerId = 'All' then
```

I didn't go through to see if there are any more occurrences of `ELSE IF` in this code.  If there are, correct them and recompile.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Maybe, it's simple nested IF ?

Comment: @Bob Jarvis My other procedures are also running with same if-else-if syntax.

Comment: I suggest you're mistaken.  `ELSE IF` is a syntax error in PL/SQL - at least through version 11.1.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Yes I am using version 11.1g

Comment: Compiling a test procedure under 11.1 I get the following error when using `ELSE IF`: `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if`.  (In other words, as typical not-particularly-helpful PL/SQL error message :-).  Changing `ELSE IF` to `ELSIF` corrects the error and the code then executes as expected.  You might want to try using ELSIF.  Oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm#484).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: ELSE IF is fully legal in Oracle, [proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9081)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I stand corrected.  Hadn't thought of this way to phrase it.  Thank you.

Comment: Well I am having a requirement which can be fulfilled using nested if else more easily then if else if ladder